# "lack of guidance" and "lack of source"

Tags: adjectives

I want to use one word to say "lack of guidance". For example, `our english study is lack of guidance.` ==> `our english study is xxx.`

I also want to use one word to say "lack of source". For example, `our city is lack of source.` ==> `our city is yyy.`

Could anyone help?

**Edit 1:** `our city is lack of source` is confusing. Here is another example:

I want to say `to do this study, our team is lack of source` (we need more data sources or more data to do this work). Is there one adjective work to replace `lack of source`?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  For the first one, do you mean "Our English study has a lack of guidance?"  Then you could just use unguided.  "Our English study is unguided."  And for your second sentence "Our city is a lack of source" I do not understand this sentence or what you're trying to say.  Could you explain it more?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: You can't use 'is lack of' in this sense; the expression is 'is lacking in' or just 'lacks' 'Our team lacks sufficient data to do this work.' I can't think of a one-word alternative.

Comment: I strongly doubt there is any single word, nor any better phrase than *lack of guidance* to mean that.
For example, *our english study is lack of guidance* is simply wrong. It should be *our study lacks guidance/ is short of guidance…* even, archaically, *wants (for) guidance.* Meanwhile *our city is lack of source* is simply incomprehensible. How could a city have a source?
It’s possible you mean *our team is lacking sources* or *… lacks sources* and either way no, there is nothing like an adjective which might work to replace *lack of source*.